# On what space of maps is Polyakov path integral actually defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, definition, path-integral, topology

This is a question more concerned about mathematical detail involving the Polyakov path integral.

In section $3.2$ of Polchinski's 1st String Theory book it is stated the following about Polyakov path integral:

> The integral runs over all Euclidean metrics and over all embeddings $X^\mu(\sigma^1,\sigma^2)$ of the world-sheet in Minkowski spacetime:
> $$\int [d X \, d g] \, \exp (-S). \tag{3.21}$$

That the path integral is defined in the space of embedings $X: \Sigma \to M$ is clear for instance in Polchinski's [Evaluation of the one loop string path integral](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01210791) and Nag's [Mathematics in and out of String Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9512010).

However, there is a reference called *Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians. Volume $2$*, whose section $1.4$, page $818$ has the following passage:

> The Polyakov action leads to well-defined transition amplitudes, obtained by
> integration over the space $\text{Met}(\Sigma)$ of all positive metrics on $\Sigma$ for a given topology, as well as over the space of all maps $\text{Map}(\Sigma, M)$: *We define*
> $$\tag{1.5} A = \sum_{\text{topologies}} \int_{\text{Met}(\Sigma)} Dg \, \frac{1}{\mathcal{N}(g)} \int_{\text{Map}(\Sigma, M)}Dx \, e^{-S[x,g,G]}.$$

In the above quote, $x: \Sigma \to M$ is a map, $g$ is a metric on $\Sigma$ and $G$ is a metric on the target space $M$.

My question can be summarized in the following: what is the precise space of maps over which the path integral is defined? I've heard that the Polyakov path integral, as other path integrals, must admit "non-standard" trajectories i.e. maps that are not necessarily bijective, or whose differential is not injective, etc.

I'm really confused because the Polyakov classical action requires at least the maps $X^\mu$ to be differenttiable. Shouldn't the space of embeddings be more well-suited for this integration, from a geometrical point of view?

Comment: The same issue crops up in the standard QM path integral: We write a $\dot{x}$ in the action but in fact the differentiable paths have measure zero - how can that be, when the action isn't even defined on non-differentiable paths? See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/739806/50583) and [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/484318/50583)

Comment: @ACuriousMind My understanding of your first answer was: The conditional Wiener measure is defined over continuous paths because you are working with Hamiltonians, so you deal with momentum $p$ instead of $\dot{x}$, so differentiability of the path is not a problem. Besides that, it seems that the equality $\mathrm{d}W_{q,q'} = \mathcal{D}q\mathrm{e}^{-S_0[q(t)]}$ is just a physicist's notation and the RHS of the equality has no formal meaning, because the action $S_0[q(t)]$ is defined only over differentiable paths.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, and my second answer explains a possible formal meaning of the $\mathcal{D}q\mathrm{e}^{-S}$ - an action on some function space (e.g. the Schwartz functions) induces a measure on the *dual* space of these functions (e.g. the tempered distributions), so this is really supposed to be that *dual* measure induced by the acton.